# How to validate presence of an array in Rails with Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My specs work fine validating login and in that validation I have access to `some_array` but in the validation for `some_array` it fails because I don't have access to it. Is there some special thing I need to do to test for arrays?

**model**

```
  validates_presence_of :login, :some_array
```

**rspec**

```
  it { should validate_presence_of(:login) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:some_array) }
```

Comment: This is not enough information to go on. Can you post your model code and your spec file (without the parts that are clearly irrelevant)?

Answer (score 1):

Not much info to go on so...

What you need to think is how is the array getting set in the first place?
With each of those it { } blocks a brand new `WhateverModel` is created.

Is `Whatever.some_array` populated on creation?

```
it { expect(WhateverModel.some_array).to_not eq([]) }
it { expect(WhateverModel.some_array).to be }

it { expect(WhateverModel.some_array).to be_kind_of Array }
```

If your "array" is some kind of model relation then there are other matchers for that.

There are tons of matchers you might see something more useful in the docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers